# Replacing a term in a sequent by a variable

Tags: proof-theory, sequent-calculus

I'm going through 'Proof Theory' by Gaisi Takeuti (second edition 1987). Theorem 6.9 on page 34 talks about when one can replace all occurrences of a term $t$ in a provable sequent $S$ by a free variable to get another provable sequent $S'$. The sufficient condition stated in the theorem is that there's no sub-semi-term of $t$ is $S$.

My question is: what examples exist where the existence of a sub-semi-term of $t$ in $S$ prevents a proof of $S'$? As far as I can tell, one can still construct a proof $P'$ of $S'$ from the original proof $P$, albeit with possibly partial replacement of $t$ in sequents other than the lowest one.

Comment: Review the syntactical specifications of page 5 and 6: *free* variables: $a_i$ and *bound* variables: $x_i$. A *term* uses free variables. Thus we have the *term* $+(a,b)$ and the formula $\exists x Px$. When we move to page 34, we have *semi-terms* that is expressions like terms where bound variables are allowed, i.e. something like $+(a,x)$. Same for semi-formulas, e.g. expressions like $Px$.

Comment: IMO the idea is that in a derivation we can always replace a *constant* with a free variable. Why the restriction? In order to avoid "capturing" by quantifiers.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks for the response. I should've probably explained the terminology in my question itself for the benefit of readers.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA This theorem seems strange (along with Takeuti's other theorems on substitution). For an example consider the sequent: $a\geq b \to a−b \geq 0$ or $G(a,b) \to G(m(a,b),0)$. Clearly, $m(a,b)$ is a term, it has sub-semi-terms: $m(a,x),m(x,b),m(x,y)$, non of which appear in the sequent. However, replacing $m(a,b)$ with a new free-variable results in the sequent: $G(a,b)\geq G(c,0)$. I do not believe this is a provable sequent? 

It makes more sense to me if $t$ is a term without free variables.